# Having some errors parsing JSON in iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, json, nsstring, nsarray

Here is my parsing code:

```
    - (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{
NSError *myError = nil;
NSDictionary *flighttrackjson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonresponse options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves  error:&myError];
NSArray *FlightStatus =  [flighttrackjson objectForKey:@"flightStatuses"];
NSString *FlightID = [FlightStatus valueForKey:@"flightId"];
NSString *DepartACode = [FlightStatus valueForKey:@"departureAirportFsCode"];
NSString *ArivalACode = [FlightStatus valueForKey:@"arrivalAirportFsCode"];
NSArray *DepartATime = [FlightStatus valueForKey:@"departureDate"];
NSArray *AriveATime = [FlightStatus valueForKey:@"arrivalDate"];
NSString *DepartTimeString = [DepartATime valueForKey:@"dateLocal"];
NSString *ArriveTimeString = [AriveATime valueForKey:@"dateUtc"];
NSArray *Delays = [FlightStatus valueForKey:@"delays"];
NSString *DepartDelayMinutes = [Delays valueForKey:@"departureGateDelayMinutes"];
NSString *ArriveDelayMinutes = [Delays valueForKey:@"arrivalGateDelayMinutes"];
NSArray *AirportInfo = [FlightStatus valueForKey:@"airportResources"];
NSString *DepartTerminal = [AirportInfo valueForKey:@"departureTerminal"];
NSString *DepartAGate = [AirportInfo valueForKey:@"departureGate"];
NSString *ArriveTerminal = [AirportInfo valueForKey:@"arrivalTerminal"];
NSString *ArriveAGate = [AirportInfo valueForKey:@"arrivalGate"];
NSString *BaggageClaim = [AirportInfo valueForKey:@"baggage"];
flightID.text=FlightID;
DepartCode.text=DepartACode;
ArrivalCode.text=ArivalACode;
DepartTime.text=DepartTimeString;
ArriveTime.text=ArriveTimeString;
DepartDelay.text=DepartDelayMinutes;
ArriveDelay.text=ArriveDelayMinutes;
DepartTerm.text=DepartTerminal;
DepartGate.text=DepartAGate;
ArriveTerm.text=ArriveTerminal;
ArriveGate.text=ArriveAGate;
Baggage.text=BaggageClaim; 
}
```

When I run that, it gives me this:

2013-02-09 21:51:40.262 Places[7083:c07] -[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8262b50
2013-02-09 21:51:40.263 Places[7083:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8262b50'

And highlights this:

return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

Does my code look bad or can someone at least explain what this error might mean?

Here is what I'm working with. http://pastebin.com/vv8ScBfZ

I'm sorry I am very new to all this.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: You should show us an excerpt from your JSON for us to help you diagnose this. But the above doesn't make sense, because you're telling us that `FlightStatus` is an `NSArray`, but then you're trying to retrieve individual `NSString` values from this array using `valueForKey`. If `FlightStatus` was an array of dictionaries, then `valueForKey` would return an array of values, not an individual `NSString`. And your error message would seem to confirm this, because it's telling you that you retrieved a `NSArray` at some point and you're trying to use it as a `NSString`.

Comment: guessing from the error, I'm thinking that you may be mis-ordering some details about the JSON structure. You're saying it's a dictionary, the items within are arrays...but is that accurate? or is it an array of items, each of which is like a dictionary?

Comment: Here is what I'm working with, thanks by the way! http://pastebin.com/vv8ScBfZ

Answer (score 2):

It looks like FlightStatus is an array with one object (a dictionary with a bunch of keys). Since it's an array you have to get that one object first, before you can use valueForKey: on its contained dictionaries. The easiest way to fix it is to change this:

```
NSArray *FlightStatus =  [flighttrackjson objectForKey:@"flightStatuses"];
```

to this:

```
NSDictionary *FlightStatus =  [[flighttrackjson objectForKey:@"flightStatuses"] lastObject];
```

Comment: Now it says: 2013-02-10 14:21:33.231 Places[8521:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8230650'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: @JonSullivan, that's probably because one of the values that you're assigning to a string is a number instead. You'll have to look through your JSON and see which one(s).